# Why suddenly Activity.java file is full of error?

Tags: android

I am a newbie in Android Development. Recently I am trying a InApp Billing for my demo app. I was using debugging mode, and at some step, it jump into the Activity.java file, which got me shocked: it's full of error! I haven't changed a thing in Activity.java file. It's provided by Android Studio. I am so confused.

[the image of the Activity.java file is here(click on it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8phd.png)

Comment: The question is very unclear. Please read the guidelines of StackOverflow to gain an understanding of how to properly pose questions on the site.

Comment: It's an android internal file. Don't worry about the errors, it's just because you aren't configured for that project and don't have 100% of the source loaded in android studio.

Comment: gotcha, thx@litelite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Framework classes, like `Activity`, refer to lots of things that are not in the Android SDK. Those things — such as `WindowControllerCallback` — will result in errors in the IDE. That is an IDE issue, as it does not know about those internal classes and methods.

So, just close the tab when you are done with it.